# What should be casted in the Web API controller?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, postman

I created a POST method in my API and I am calling it through Postman. Although everything works fine and the object gets inserted in the database, Postman gives me HTTP status code 204 No content - as in, there is no content to be outputted. The way I wrote the code, I assumed it should output the object that I have created.

**TitleController.cs**

```
[HttpPost()]
public IActionResult InsertTitle([FromBody] GtlTitle gtlTitle)
{
    try
        {
            return Ok(_gtlTitleRepository.InsertTitle(gtlTitle));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
}
```

**IGtlTitleRepository.cs**

```
GtlTitle InsertTitle(GtlTitle gtlTitle);
```

**MockGtlTitleRepository.cs**

```
public GtlTitle InsertTitle([FromBody] GtlTitle gtlTitle)
{

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        return connection.ExecuteScalar<GtlTitle>(@"INSERT INTO GTL_TITLE (ISBN, VolumeName, TitleDescription, PublicationDate, AuthorID, PublisherID, TempID) 
                                                        VALUES (@ISBN, @VolumeName, @TitleDescription, @PublicationDate, @AuthorID, @PublisherID, @TempID)",
                                                       new
                                                       {
                                                           gtlTitle.ISBN,
                                                           gtlTitle.VolumeName,
                                                           gtlTitle.TitleDescription,
                                                           gtlTitle.PublicationDate,
                                                           gtlTitle.AuthorID,
                                                           gtlTitle.PublisherID,
                                                           gtlTitle.TempID
                                                       });
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What should I return (and in which controller) in order to retrieve the object after the POST method is completed in Postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not returning anything from your SQL.
You probably want to update your SQL to return the inserted ID.

You could do it like this:

```
INSERT into GTL_TITLE <list of fields> VALUES <list of values>
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

If you want to return the whole object then you need to run an extra select statement using the ID you just figured out

```
SELECT <list of fields> FROM GTL_TITLE 
WHERE your_primary_key_field = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

if you read the documentation you'll see example of this in action:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

I haven't done SQL in a while so this will probably require some updates to the syntax

Divide this in 2 parts.

1. get the simple SQL part working first. Make sure you can insert objects and you get the inserted id back.
   Once you do this, get the code part working with a simple id. You want to get in a position where you run the code and you get an id back in your code.
2. Once the first part is working then go a little more complicated and return the whole object repeating the same procedure.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it didn't work. My method still does not return any content.

Comment: added a few steps which should help you make this work, start simple from sql and work your way up to code from there.